# The "Drupal way" to Wizard Steps?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, wizard

I'm working on a custom module in Drupal with a multi-page form approach, and I'd like to have a visualization of steps.

Step 1 > [_Step_2_] > Step 3 > Finish

Business Rules:

- they always see all the steps, and the step they are on now
- they can go back to any step they completed
- but they can't skip ahead to a step, say step 2 if they didn't finish step 1

Q1 : 
What's the best/ most Drupal-correct or Drupal-intuitive way to implement this?

I looked around a little and found this : [image: Thimble screenshot]

Q2 : Is this a good option ?
It looks like they are using the hook_menu system here ( MENU_LOCAL_TASK )  - how would I prevent the user from skipping ahead to steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is with variable functions. See

http://www.benjeavons.com/multi-step-forms-drupal-6-using-variable-functions (D6)
http://growingventuresolutions.com/blog/drupal-7-multistep-forms-using-variable-functions (D7)

You can also use the form wizard in Chaos Tools which employs the same approach though I've never used that myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module called `webform` which I believe provides this functionality out of the box. You could use a `webform` node to implement your multi step form, then handle the submission in your module.

Comment: Webform form responses are not stored as nodes, so you should be aware of this before choosing Webform for a project. That being said, the Webform module is pretty great, and yes, it support multistep forms out of the box.